# Refreshing UITableViewCell after fetching image data by dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, setneedsdisplay

I'm writing app that shows TableView with entries that contains images.
I'm trying to fetch image by executing this line of code inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text =  [artistData objectForKey:generesKey];
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
         NSURL *url_img = [NSURL URLWithString:[artistData objectForKey:pictureKey]];
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                         url_img];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshCell:) withObject:cell waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
```

After setting image I perform selector that contains:

```
-(void)refreshCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell{
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.tableViewOutlet setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

And image is not shown but when I click on cell or scroll entire list, images are shown. Why my View is not refreshing? Did I missed something?

Comment: Much easier will be use some framework for async images downloading. For example SDWebImage https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage and then you only need to write `[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://somelink.png"]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll could always reload the cell by calling `[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];`

In order to prevent the infinite loop once you successfully download an image you'll want to cache the results. How long you cache is up to you.

```
 NSCache *imageCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
 imageCache.name = @"My Image Cache";
 UIImage *image = [imageCache objectForKey:url_img];
 if (image) {
    cell.imageView.image = image;
 } else {
    // Do your dispatch async to fetch the image.

    // Once you get the image do
    [imageCache setObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data] forKey:url_img];
}
```

You'll want the imageCache to be a property at the ViewController level. Don't create one each time in`cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: This is causing to endles loop of calling cellForRowAtIndexPath: because you want to refresh it, and it call this method.

Comment: Well you could cache the image and use that instead. Trying looking at NSCache for temporary caching.

Answer (score 4):

It should be enough to call **`setNeedsLayout()`** on a cell.
In **swift** 4 it looks like this:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: imageUrl)!)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        cell.setNeedsLayout()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to interacting with the UI from a background queue. Try this:

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    NSURL *url_img = [NSURL URLWithString:[artistData objectForKey:pictureKey]];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url_img];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    });
});
```

Comment: No, this is not working, still image is shown after clicking or scrolling:/